# Change isotope options on click

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-isotope

I just want to change the value of isResizeBound from true to false on click after isotope plugin initialization.

Is there an easy way?

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
 isResizeBound: true
});

$(".aa").on("click", function() {
 $grid.isotope({ isResizeBound: false });
});
```

This is what I tried.

```
var trueorfalse = true;

var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    isResizeBound: trueorfalse
});

$(".aa").on("click", function() {
  trueorfalse = false;
  // trigger isotope again
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

Comment: Probably there is an easy way. What have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: Hello.I updated my post.